# Fast and Slow motion video detection using Optical Flow

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing, motion, motion-detection

I'm trying to calculate a "video motion" value in a given video sequence, meaning how fast or slow motion the video is. For instance, if a video is about a car racing, the value is high. Whereas if the video is about two persons standing/talking, then the motion is low.

What comes into my mind is using optical flow which is already an implemented function in OpenCV. I never used it. But I don't know if that's a good idea, and if yes, how to interpret it to a "motion value".

Is optical flow applicable here? How to use it for my purpose?